# How to add content to add-entry in forms in zenity?

Tags: bash, shell, zenity

I have a form with entries in zenity

```
zenity --forms --add-entry="Name" --add-entry="Surname"
```

and I want to add deafult content to them so for example next to "Name" would be "Your name" (user would of course be able to change it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`--entry` is the only option than accept default value, but you can not define more than one entry :

```
zenity --entry --title="Add your name" --text="Enter your name" --entry-text="Your name"
```